# $\lim_{x \to 1} {P(x^n)\over P(x^m)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

if $P$ is a polynomial and $n,m\in\Bbb N^*$ and $P(1)=0$ find: $$\lim_{x \to 1} {P(x^n)\over P(x^m)}$$
Let $P(x)=a_νx^ν+a_{ν-1}x^{ν-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$ and I used L'Hôpital's rule and I found that $$\lim_{x \to 1} {P(x^n)\over P(x^m)}={n\over m}$$ which I'm not sure if it's the correct answer. I'd like a help/hint (maybe without L'Hôpital's rule).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that the polynomial has a root at $1$, hence we can rewrite $P(x) = (1-x)^k\cdot Q(x)$ for some polinomial $Q$ with $Q(1)\neq 0$.

We then have:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{P(x^n)}{P(x^m)} =\frac{Q(1)}{Q(1)}\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{(1-x^n)^k}{(1-x^m)^k}$$

Now we can use Hospital iteratively: 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{(1-x^n)^k}{(1-x^m)^k}=^H
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{k(1-x^n)^{k-1}nx^{n-1}}{k(1-x^m)^{k-1}mx^{m-1}}
=\frac nm\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{(1-x^n)^{k-1}}{(1-x^m)^{k-1}}=\frac{n^k}{m^k}$$

Comment: Or use L'Hopital just once, on $(1-x^n)/(1-x^m)$, and then take the $k$th power, using $\lim(f(x)^k)=(\lim f(x))^k$ (provided the limit exists).